# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists and find it

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Let $x_1 = 0$ and for $n>1$,
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n^2 + 1}{2}.$$
Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists and find it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! :) Please try to format your equations using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Click on the link for the tutorials.

Comment: $x=(x^2+1)/2\implies x=1$

Comment: Please show us the own efforts. Considering the function $f(x)=(x^2+1)/2$, and the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$, what are the fix points of $f$? Is $g$ monotone? Can you show the sequence is bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From AM-GM, we have:

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n^2+1) \geq x_n$$

so the sequence is increasing. Also, if $x_n \leq 1$, we have:

$$x_{n+1} =\frac{1}{2}(x_n^2+1)\leq \frac{1}{2}(1+1) = 1$$

so with induction (the base case is trivial), the sequence is bounded and thus convergent. If $L$ is its limit, then:

$$L=\frac{1}{2}(L^2+1) \Rightarrow (L-1)^2=0\Rightarrow L = 1$$

Comment: You have a typo.  $(L-1)^2 = 0 \implies L = 1$.  (Can't have a positive increasing function have a limit *less* than all it values, can we ;).....)

Comment: @fleablood, Edited, thanks.